# How can I get progress bar dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking for the solution for progress barstyling. All I want is to append styling basded on the percentage I am getting through backend.

[image]

Let say here I am getting 73% for the green. So All I want to apply class using

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, green 73%, orange 73% 100%);
```

Now I want it in ts file. Let say I have class name 'progress-bar' so how can I append this styling in the class from ts file ?

Note: I am looking for ts file solution as the progrss bar is dynamically generated so I don't have any html available for that.

Comment: Have you tried angular material progress bar?

Comment: Actually as I mentioned in Note this is already there all I need to do is to apply this style by appending it to class.  @GangadharGandi

Comment: paste you html code please

Comment: It will be much easier if you provide the code

Comment: Are your colors dynamic or will it be same always(green and orange)?

Comment: @Arcteezy colors will be same only percentage will be dynamic.

Comment: I know code is required but here just need to append the style to css so I dont know how can I achieve it. All I was doing is to apply the className to that container. But that is not the case here. @GangadharGandi

Comment: you can use property binding by `[style.background-color]` or use angular's directive `[ngStyle]`. Refer this https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-ngstyle-in-angular-for-dynamic-styling

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-bootstrap widgets it's provide almost same progress bar you need.

Example: [ng-Bootstrap progress bar](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar/examples)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngStyle`,

```
[ngStyle]="{'background':'linear-gradient(to right, '+progressColor+' '+progress+'%, '+remainingProgressColor+' '+progress+'%'}"
```

> I made the colors also to be dynamic. You can change it as per requirement.

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivscqa

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Renderer2` to add dynamic styles

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
    const progress = 73;
    this.renderer.setStyle(
        this.el.nativeElement,
        'background',
        `linear-gradient(to right,  green ${progress}%, orange ${progress}% 100%)`
      );
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://angular-w9jzvh.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

if your progress-bar is your custom made,
you can try

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'background': styleExp}">...</some-element>
```

where you can give your "styleExp" expression from .ts file

more at https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 0):

Easy and Simple way:

You can try using `[ngStyle]`
You can take two variables (or more depending on your colors).

Let's say `x` and `y`, assign values to them

Then you can do:

```
getStyle() {
return {background: `linear-gradient(to right, green ${this.x}%, orange 
${this.y}% 100%)`};
}     

[ngStyle]="getStyle()"
```

or you can do inline:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(to right, green '+ x + '%' + ', orange ' + y + '% ' + '100%)'}"
```